# Oracle query taking infinite time in PHP

Tags: php, sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

When i run below Query in PHP it takes infinite time.
And when I run it in sqldeveloper it takes some milliseconds only.

I have no idea why it takes so much time in PHP.

```
select 'This is a Fast Fix' as msg
            from V_MYVIEW a
            where a.entity_id = :entity_id
                and rownum=1
                and a.description like 'Fast Fix%'
```

Also to mention this query used to run properly and all of sudden this has started taking infinite time.
Also this query runs properly in dev env.

What could be the possible error. Any help would be appreciated.

Also there is no problem when i run the below query in PHP

```
select description as msg
                from V_MYVIEW a
                where a.entity_id = :entity_id
                    and rownum=1
                    and a.description like 'Fast Fix%'
```

the only difference between the two queries is

```
select description as msg  ==>select 'This is a Fast Fix' as msg
```

Comment: @Radagast81 I use same user in PHP as well as sqldeveloper..but i get the result in sqldeveloper when i fire the query...and in PHP it keeps on waiting

Comment: When you run it in SQL Developer are you binding in :entity_id or are you putting in some specific value?

Comment: I advise you not to use rownum, rather use "fetch first 1 rows only".

Comment: @KevinSeymour I am binding the entity_id